# Django password form assign widget doesn't work

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm creating a registration form for my website and everything functions, except the 'password1' and 'password2' won't recognize the widgets I assign to them. Below is a part of my code, which should be relevant to the issue from my *forms.py* file. Note the email part works correctly.

EDIT: put the whole Form in, also don't mind the identation, it's correct in my file

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['password1', 'password2', 'email']
    widgets = {
        'password1': forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                   'placeholder': 'Wachtwoord'}
        ),
        'password2': forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                   'placeholder': 'Wachtwoord'}
        ),
        'email': forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                   'placeholder': 'E-mailadres'}
        ),
    }
```

Below is a part of the *registration.html* in which the form is drawn. The top part is from the **last name** part which functions normally, the bottom part is from **password1** which doesn't function:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="last_name" class="text-info">
        {{lid_form.last_name.label}}</label>
    {{lid_form.last_name}}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="password1" class="text-info">
        {{user_form.password1.label}}</label>
    {{user_form.password1}}
  </div>
```

[Picture Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmQlk.png)

Comment: can you post your whole form class? It's not clear where are you specifying the `widgets` variable. Afaik the widget needs to be set as a property of a formfield.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I edited my opening post